# Identify row number where all values match vector

Tags: r

I have a matrix:

```
a<-replicate(3,sample(c(0,1),4, replace=T))
```

and a vector:

```
b<-c(0,1,0)
```

I would like to identify the row number in `a` that corresponds to the vector `b`.

looking at `a==b` I can see the row where each condition returns `TRUE`, but how can I obtain the row number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(42)
a < -replicate(3, sample(c(0, 1), 4, replace=T))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    1
#[2,]    1    1    1
#[3,]    0    1    0
#[4,]    1    0    1


b <- c(0, 1, 0)

#vector recycling is done in row direction --> transpose the matrix
#logical values get coerced to integers in colSums   
which(colSums(t(a) == b) == 3L)
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(1)
a <- replicate(3,sample(c(0,1),4, replace=T))
b<-c(0,1,0)
which(apply(a, 1, FUN=function(x) all(x == b)))
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(15)
a <- replicate(5,sample(c(0,3),6, replace=T))
b<-c(0,1,0)
which(apply(a, 1, FUN=function(x) all(x == b)))
```